# namespace of global __builtin__ conflicts with module namespace

Tags: python, string, namespaces, built-in

I have written a simple function that allows me to parse a string with a variable type (following the method described in this SO question [Lexical cast from string to type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11775460/lexical-cast-from-string-to-type)). I have a module called **ascii_tools** that contains the following function:

```
def get_builtin(name):
    return getattr(__builtins__, name)
```

So, this works as follows.

```
get_builtin(desired_type)(some_input_string)
```

This parses my string for desired_type='float' or 'int', saving me some hard-coding for some applications requiring string parsing.

When I define the get_builtin function directly into a python interpreter, this function behaves properly. However, when I try to call this function via ascii_tools.get_builtin('float'), I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'float'
```

Same error occurs for 'int' input. This seemed strange, since the method works just fine when defined in the global namespace of the interpreter. So I checked the output of pdb, which is:

```
NameError: name 'ascii_tools' is not defined
```

This must have something to do with the namespace of **builtins**. Maybe calls to **builtins** somehow check the namespace of the module the call is nested in, and this is causing the problem?

Comment: The `NameError` is unrelated.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the relevant post, @MartijnPieters , although for some reason "import builtins" does not work for me "ImportError: No module named builtins"

Comment: On Python 3 the module has been renamed to [`builtins`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html) (no underscores). The Python 2 version of the documentation should have included a banner at the top informing you of the name change but I see that that is missing; I'll file a Python documentation bug report.

Comment: Ok, but given that I am running on python 2.7.x, how can I import the builtins module so that I can solve my problem? Without being able to do that, I cannot implement your solution.

Comment: Sorry, got my posts mixed up. In Python 2 it is called [`__builtin__`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__builtin__.html).

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me, @MartijnPieters , problem solved.

Comment: Any chance you can point me to how I can call the builtins module so that my call will be both python 2 and 3 compatible? Maybe with a __future__ call somehow?

Comment: Use exception handling; `try: import __builtin__ as builtins`, `except ImportError: import builtins`.

Comment: Durr, that should have been obvious. Thanks again for all the help!