# Python datatypes to pyspark.sql.types auto conversion

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I need to create dataframe based on the set of columns names and data types. But data types are given in str, int, float etc.. but I need to convert these to StringType, IntegerType etc.. needed for StructType/StructField.

I can create simple mapping do the job but I like to know if there any automatic conversion of these type?

Comment: Can you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427185/how-to-make-good-reproducible-apache-spark-dataframe-examples)? There might be an easier way, but it's hard to tell without seeing exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: Below is the example but I have field names and type in python i.e. str and int. schema = StructType([
            StructField("city", StringType(), True),
            StructField("country", StringType(), True),
            StructField("population", IntegerType(), True)])

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know it's been long, but you can try the following:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import _parse_datatype_string
```

then you can use it as follows:

```
_parse_datatype_string('int') # Will convert it to IntegerType of pyspark
```

NOTE: The type has to be in String format

Reference: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/types.html

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by using the following function:

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.types import _infer_type
>>> _infer_type([1.0, 2.0])
ArrayType(DoubleType,true)
```

If you have the type directly in the input you can also do this:

```
>>> my_type = type(42)
>>> _infer_type(my_type())
LongType
```

Finally, If you only have a string describing the python type you can use this:

```
>>> from pydoc import locate
>>> _infer_type(locate('int'))
LongType
```

Sources:

- [pyspark.sql.types source code](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/types.html)
- [Lexical cast from string to type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11775460/lexical-cast-from-string-to-type)