# How to cast data types using getattr() and types.builtins in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a function called casting() that can cast data types using the getattr() procedure. However, I am having trouble getting the function to work correctly.

```
import types, inspect

def casting(data='123', string_type='int'):
    try: return getattr(types.builtins, string_type)(data)
    except: return None
```

When I try to use the casting() function to cast a string to an integer, I get None due to following error

```
>>> print(getattr(types.builtins, 'int')('123'))
AttributeError: module 'types' has no attribute 'builtins
```

I have checked the documentation, found that int is a member of types.builtins and found same with code.

```
>>> print(inspect.getmembers(types)[29][1]['__name__'])
builtins
```

I thinks, 'types.builtins' is not correct, there might be a right why hence seeking help

Comment: `getattr(__builtins__, 'int')`?

Comment: Don't use module [`types`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html), use module [`builtins`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html).

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11775460/lexical-cast-from-string-to-type answers your question?

Comment: Why would you do this in the first place?

Comment: @Abdul Niyas P M bto,  getattr(__builtins__, 'int') not worked

Comment: @KamilCuk brother, yours reference is similar.. eval was an option but i did not want to use it.

Comment: Hi. I linked to a question asked. The answers to that questions are releavnt. One answer mentions locate here https://stackoverflow.com/a/29831586/9072753 and the other uses builtins here https://stackoverflow.com/a/11776132/9072753 .

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`builtins`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html) module.

```py
import builtins

def cast(data, string_type="int"):
    try:
        return getattr(builtins, string_type)(data)
    except (ValueError, TypeError):
        return None
```

Couple of suggestions:

- Format your code according to pep8
- Do not use bare `except` clause.
- I see no reason for `data` to have default value. It is what the user wants to cast.

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks for the feedback. I got curios to learn more about it. Do you have any link for that?

Comment: Please refer to the last note in the documentation of [`builtins`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html#module-builtins), where it is pointed out that `__builtins__` may refer to the `__dict__` attribute of the module instead.

Comment: `ValueError` is not enough, e.g. `cast(1, 'list')`

Comment: yes arguments has no default value, just writen it in question for clarity. thanks.